# Transformation of nested lists into a list of sets in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Having a list of equally sized lists, e.g.:

```
(def d [["A" "B"] ["A" "C"] ["H" "M"]])
```

How can it be transformed into a list of sets, each set for the indexes above:

```
[#{"A" "H"} #{"B" "C" "M"}]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
(map set (apply map vector d))
```

"`(apply map vector)`" is what is called "zip" in other languages like Python. It calls `vector` on the first item of each element of `d`, then the second item of each element, etc.

Then we call `set` on each of those collections.

Comment: nice - +1 for a very neat solution!

Answer (score 4):

if hash-set allowed duplicate keys, you could use:

```
(apply map hash-set d)
```

instead, you can do the uglier

```
(apply map (fn [& s] (set s)) d)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

```
(reduce
  (fn [sets vals]
    (map conj sets vals))
  (map hash-set (first d))
  (rest d))
```